# SPA and refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am creating Angular single page application and I want to use JWT (JSON web tokens) with OAUTH 2.0. I was reading best practices and found OAuth 0 article which should help with it https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use.

My app should be able to login user and keep him logged for 60 days. I know that storing access token in browser for 60 days is not very secure and it is recommended to have it short lived. So I was thinking to use Refresh Token and store it in HttpOnly Secure Cookie to not allow read it from client side Javascript, but in this auth0 article they say that this is very insecure and SPA should not use Refresh tokens, but they are not describing why.

What if my auth API code exchange endpoint return access_token in JSON response but refresh_token in HttpOnly cookie? This way I don't need to expose any system secret keys, because they are stored in auth backend API.

Can somebody provide more information and tell is it secure to store refresh token in HttpOnly Secure cookie?

Answer (score 3):

SPA application uses the OAuth2 implicit flow and there is no refresh token for this flow because public client application can't store the system password safely. I would suggest to implement the OpenID Connect implicit flow and store the JWT token in local storage. This token is more secure and can't be used by any other application. You can also encrypt the token to secure the sensitive information. If you are looking for more information, please visit a short linked-in article https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microservices-security-openid-connect-manish-singh

Comment: But what if my code exchange endpoint return access token in JSON response but refresh token in HttpOnly cookie? I don't need to expose any system password because it is stored in my backend auth API.

Comment: It looks like your are using API gateway or similar to set the refresh token in the secure cookie response. Storing RT in http only cookie is secure from security point of view. But I think your implementation is prone to CSRF attack if you are getting AT in the JSON response using RT only and not using any other security.

Comment: I have read your provided article about OpenID and yes I'm using some Proxy API to store all private keys in backend, thanks :)

Comment: @ManishSingh can you explain why it would be vuln to CSRF? CSRF attacks cannot view responses.

Comment: Let's me describe through example, if attacker wants to change the user's eMail and token is stored in HTTP only secure cookie, flow will be - 1. User is logged in example.com 2. User visits an attacker's domain (hacking-application.com) 3. Attacker tricks the user's browser into sending a request that change the user's eMail (example.com) 4. Authentication cookie with token is appended by user's browser to this request 5. User's email address is changed.

Comment: Sorry... I'm a bit late to the party; been the case here lately regarding these topics. So to understand what, you @ManishSingh , are saying with regard to micro services. This is the process I'm envisioning in my head...

1. You have an api gateway with which you have a separate oauth/openid authentication. From that server you could technically send an httponly cookie containing an access token back to the client

2. The api gateway could then authenticate with the authorization server retrieving and storing it's response (the access_token and refresh_token) to be used on the secured api

Answer (score 2):

Along with the answer form @ManishSingh that using OpenID Connect you should use [PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce) where no client secret is required.